# Jest - Cannot find File with relative import path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I have my tests running on my Project(React/Typescript). Every Test is running perfectly. But suddenly without installing/uninstalling anything, when I tried to add one more test suite. I get this error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@babel/polyfill/lib/noConflict' from 'index.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        '../index.tsx'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string
```

Which is super weird. All my other tests, have relative imports and are running just fine. My jest config is perfect, and it includes all the default options that jest suggest.

I tried, the test to be inside an `__tests__` directory, with no luck. I tried, to put it inside the same root as the component, with no luck. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: One more point. Inlcuding the file extension, with the import fixes this problem, but it is against our policies. Which results in another TS Error this time. So, that is out of the question.

Comment: are you importing this manually? 1- if no: just install it: `npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill` . 2- if you're manually importing it: this file doesn't seems to be a module (it doesn't export anything). it's just a js script which requires some packages.

Comment: Today i faced similar issue after installing a package. i found out the that package was dependent on another version of `babel`. so after installing it, the version of babel changed at it caused the problem. so maybe your jest is old, and the babel is upgraded, or such package version incompatibles issues like this.